# Is it possible to allow a class to be cast to arbitrary enums?

Tags: c++, class, enums, casting

Background: we have an embedded processor with specialised integer types.  We have an emulation of these types in C++ to allow the code to be built under Visual Studio or gcc and have calculations produce the same values as they would on the embedded processor.

The following code compiles fine for the embedded processor (where `int_t` is our custom integer type):

```
enum foo { VAL_0, VAL_1, VAL_2 };
int_t my_val = VAL_1;
foo foo_val = (foo)val;
```

The compiler for the embedded processor treats int_t as a normal integer type in the same way as int, hence casting it to an enum is legal in the same way as casting an int to enum is.

The C++ emulation of `int_t` is a class that overloads the various operators to give them the same behaviour as the embedded type.

We want to allow this code to also compile under emulation for any arbitrary enum.  Obviously we could add a cast operator to any specific enum in the class, but we are providing a generic library and we want to allow the developers to do this for any arbitrary enum they may develop or use.

Is there any way to implement this behaviour in C++ so that it behaves exactly equivalently to a standard int type in this case?

Comment: A non-explicit template conversion operator `enable_if`'d by `is_enum`. Sounds a bit convoluted, I think there may be a better design decision.

Comment: The underlying type of an enum is an integral type, so it's always safe to cast to another integral type. Something like this: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/f3ImG6hAfQdgwnih

Comment: I assume you are asking because `foo foo_val = (foo)val;` fails in the emulation environment with an error similar to `error: invalid cast from type 'int_t' to type 'E'`. Why don't you just write `E(int(my_val))`? That should work (I hope/assume without overhead on the embedded) on both platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++11's [`std::is_enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum) and some sfinae to limit the constructor:

```
template<typename E> 
int_t::int_t(E e, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<E>::value>::type* = nullptr)
```

Or in C++14's slightly tidier form:

```
template<typename E> 
int_t::int_t(E e, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<E>::value>* = nullptr)
```

And in C++17's tidiest:

```
template<typename E> 
int_t::int_t(E e, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<E>>* = nullptr)
```

---

#### Edit:

I did it originally in the wrong direction. To allow conversions *to* an enum, and only to an enum, you'd write a conversion operator in a similar fashion:

```
template<typename E, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<E>::value>* = nullptr>
operator E() { return E{val}; }
```

Comment: I'd also allow the constructor to accept any integral type (assuming that OP is right in that `int_t` should really behave like `int`). See my comment on the OP.

Comment: @AndyG - That is certainly the approach I would follow. But I think that the substituting `int_t` for `int` may fail under certain circumstances if there is no direct c'tor/conversion operator. That ever present "single user defined conversion" during overload resolution.

Comment: With slight modification, this did the trick:

    // Conversion to an enum
    template<typename E, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<E>::value>* = nullptr>
    operator E()
    {
        return (E)val;
    }

Comment: Hmm.  Couldn't persuade it to format that code properly.
The key difference was using
`return (E)val;`
i.e. a cast to E rather than an instantiation.

Comment: It is a nice solution; but (this may be a question to the OP) why is it desirable to allow only conversions to enums? On the embedded system one can convert to any arithmetic type, and any type which has a ctor with an int arg. Wouldn't one try to emulate that, which, I think, @Pskocik's solution does?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I have to confess the same thought was going through my mind when I looked at it.  At the moment the complaint was specifically about enums, so that's what I needed to get going.  We have had quite a lot of problems with our emulation of the embedded compiler when we opened up too many conversions - it leads to a whack-a-mole of ambiguous operators - so I didn't want to get too generic until I was sure I had a solution.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - The problem I have with an implicit unconstrained template type conversion operator, that does a cast, is that it's potentially too permissive. Now a static cast isn't all that bad, since it's not *too* permissive, but I'd personally rather constrain the interface to the smallest white-list of types I would want to support.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could provide a template cast operator that attempts to cast the integer representation:

```
class int_t{
public:
    int_t(int X) {}

    template<typename T>
    operator T(){ return static_cast<T>(42); }
};

enum foo { VAL_0, VAL_1, VAL_2 };
int main()
{
    int_t my_val = VAL_1;
    foo foo_val = (foo)my_val;
}
```

This will fail to instantiate if your integer value of `int_t` fails to `static_cast` to the target type.

If you want `int_t`  to follow  the `int` type as closely as possible, I'd probably prefer this over restricting the cast to just `enum`s.

Comment: It's a valid suggestion, and I did have the same thought when putting in the is_enum approach.  I will need to see if this opens up too many ambiguities in the type hierarchy - every time we add another cast, it seems to spawn multiple ambiguous operators somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

As indicated in my comment, a very simple solution is to use a two-step conversion like `E(int(my_val))`. On the embedded target the `int()` conversion is redundant and does probably nothing, or just a conversion to another integer type, as does the `E()` conversion.

In the emulation, the `int()` conversion actually invokes the user-defined conversion operator, as desired.

Comment: I don't want the developer to have to do anything to get it to work like an int.  To them it _is_ an int.